# Creating custom theme in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: theme, magento-2.2.5, custom-theme

I am using windows OS. I have configured grunt already.

In Magento 2.2.5, I have created the custom theme called "cluster". I followed [this turorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html). While doing the `setup-content:deploy` i am getting this error.
[image]

Update:
I have `\app\design\frontend\Vendor\cluster\web\css\email-inline.less` file with below content.

```
@import 'source/_variables.less';
```

I have `source\_variables.less` with [this content](https://pastebin.com/v4v242F5).

Comment: try once with rm -rf generated and clear cache php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush after that re-try to deploy

Comment: @Hit's, I have tried these comments many times.

Comment: Ok, Is your app/design/frontend/Customtheme/default/web/css OR app/design/frontend/Customtheme/default/Magento_Theme/web/css contain any css files?

Comment: @Hits, Please check my updated question